# Problem with using YCS ( YChatSharp )

Tags: c#, yahoo-api

As i posted before, i want to create a simple GUI for Yahoo! Protocol 16. I want to use [ycs](http://ycs.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ycs/) library, but it hasn't any documentation. Could any one please introduce documentation about this library ?

Thanks about your attention.

Comment: There is a whole folder full of test code in the repository - can't you study that?

Comment: I studied it, but it is not complete. This test only contains sending pm and logging in yahoo. I want to know about the keys and values that use in creating packets!

Comment: From reading your question, how would a potential answerer know that is what you are looking for?

Comment: I want any one who works with this library help me, or if possible introduce me a documentation.

Comment: I wrote the SMS library for YCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the other languages based API's source, i think it was very useful for you to understand the structure of Yahoo! Protocol,

http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/y/ymsglib/ymsglib-0.1.zip

http://sunet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jymsg9/jymsg9/v0.64%2C%20Alpha%20release/ymsg_code_source_v0_64.zip

And also you can check the following link to get information about yahoo protocol:

http://carbonize.co.uk/ymsg16.html

http://www.venkydude.com/articles/yahoo.htm